# Scraping Set Store Location

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My customer has asked me to scrape a hardware store to retrieve their product details and pricing.

I created a script using Beautiful Soup which:

- scrapes the site,
- parses the info for each product,
- appends the details to a list,
- once the scrape is finished, writes this data to a csv file.

My code is working just fine, except for the price. The product prices do not show up, unless I can somehow set the store location in the code.

For the time being, and to check my coding works, I have added the try / except code below.

```
    try:
        p_price = p.find('span', class_='mz-price').text
except:
        p_price = 0.00
```

Is there some way I can set the store location in my code.

Comment: can you share the URL and may be price are dynamic generated!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for us to resolve fully automatically without knowing the site.

You can get some insight by using developer tools of your browser and studying  requests being send by your browser when setting up the location:

[How to view browser requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287904/how-to-view-browser-requests)

Maybe you can partially solve this by setting the location manually, downloading the resulting HTML document and running the parser on the result.

Comment: I am trying to scrape homehardware.ca.
I have tried doing to the store locator page, and set the store to Toronto, ON. That is as far as I could get